# Referral Exclusion List Not Working (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I've set up a bunch of referral exclusion domains like the following:

```
mydomain.com
paypal.com
```

But when I view the "All Referrals" tab under "Acquisition", I still see `mydomain.com` and `paypal.com`.

**How come mydomain.com and other domains under the Referral Exclusion list are appearing under the All Referrals tab?**

I setup www --> non-www redirects, as well configured each page to have the SAME Google Tag Manager code.

When I click on `mydomain.com`, it looks like the following:

```
/
/page1/
/page2/
/page4/
/page5/
/etcc......
```

I'm not sure what's going on, but I keep getting `mydomain.com` listed in the All Referrals tab even though I explicitly stated to exclude it.

Comment: This question isn't programing related you might want to try asking in the Google+ community https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/114481059214254340537

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Analytics.

Comment: i found this question relevant because Google Analytics is very related to web programming

Answer (score 10):

Make sure to look at % new visitors column head.  In most cases, this actually is fixed - but it will not fix retroactive and it will not cease for any visitors who were previous self referrals and visit via direct source going forward until the cookie resets.

You may still see mydomain.com & paypal.com in your referral list, but if you change the time frame to when you implemented referral exclusions, you should see any of those referrals have 0% new visits.